# Understanding the purpose of this D flip flop circuit

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I'm struggling to understand the purpose of this circuit.

As far as I know, this is not an edge-triggered Flip Flop.

Q0 = x
D1 = Q0 and X'
Y = Q1 and X

**What I know**

So in order to get one in the output, I need to set 1 in the first flip flop and X = 1.

If I set X = 1 when CLK is 1, Q0 will be 1.

If I set X to 0 when CLK = 0 I will have 1 at the D input of the first flip flop

When CLK goes to HIGH I will have Q0 = 0 this will force D to 0.

**Problem**

So my understanding is that the first flip flop needs to be set before Q0 goes to LOW and X needs to go to HIGH to get 1 at the output.

I did the simulation in Quartus to try to understand but it doesn't matter what I do Y is always 0

**My thoughts**

Maybe this is an edge-triggered flip flop? If this is the case I can achieve Y = 1 by setting the X to 1 waiting for Q0 = 1, setting X to 0, wait for Q1 = 0, and finally set X back to one to enable the output.
But even if this is the case, I don't see the purpose of the circuit.

[image]

Exercise for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: All D flip flops are edge triggered

Comment: Oh, I see that I'm confusing d-latch with d-flip-flop, so this acts as a sequence detector, right? I just draw the transition table and it looks like if I input 101 Y becomes active